# why ubuntu mail command didnt work?

Tags: linux, email, ubuntu-16.04

I sent a mail to my company email address and `yahoo.com` email address in company network. my company email box can receive the mail while yahoo.com email box not.

I use command as :`echo "aaa" | mail -s "test" ****@****.com`

I have modified

```
/etc/mail/sendmail.mc .Change DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl
to DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=0.0.0.0')dnl
```

I keep `/etc/mail.rc` empty.

Why the outer mail box can not receive the mail?

Comment: Did you check the spam folder?

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio , yes, I have checked many times.